Create 'n' number of child components from LWC property editor
This has probably been asked before, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for, maybe someone can help.
The functionality I'm looking to achieve in a custom LWC is very similar to the new-ish standard flow Datatable screen component.  Where in the datatable you can define a column.  Do you want to define another?  CLick "Add column".  Another? "Click "Add..." again.
Now, suppose I'm creating a simple LWC that renders a button with 2 properties in the property editor:

Button Label
Button HREF target

Can I also then have a "New Button" option in the property editor where someone placing this component on a record page or flow screen can define any n number of buttons (where n is any integer value).  When "New Button" is selected, they then must define Label and HREF target for button 2, button 3 etc.  An alternative to this might be a 3rd property on the init component called "How many buttons", and the Integer value used will generate the required missing property fields for input.
Saves me from having to manually build the required number of buttons in the template.. and what if different groups need different variances of counts?  Looking to do this dynamically.
Thanks
